# Azure Active Directory Authentication Process with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin.ios, active-directory, adal

I have my application registered with Azure AD and have got the required details to perform application authentication with Azure AD.

But when i run 
**new AuthenticationContext(UserContext.AzureCommonAuthority);**

this line it throws an exception-

"The type initializer for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.TokenCache' threw an exception." with error code 
"**cannot_access_publisher_keychain**".

Working with Xamarin.iOS project.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem , im working on it if i found the solution ill post it.

EDIT : I was testing on the iphone simulator , i dont get any error on a real device :/

Comment: @Davind Thanks for a reply. Yes i tried it with device and it is working. Not sure what is the problem with simulator.

Comment: I am getting it in device only, what to do?